# Issue with playbook

Tags: jenkins, ansible

I am relatively new to ansible. I have configured Jenkins-Ansible to run some jobs. My main.yml file contains :

```
    - name: Check for <user1>
      become: false
      become_user: <user1>
      shell: "/path/on/destination/server/<applicationhealthcheck.sh>
      register: output
      ignore_errors: yes
      when: <variable1> == "<user1>" or <variable1> == "<user2>"
      tags:
        - check
        - start

    - name: Show output
      debug: 
        msg: "{{ output.stdout_lines }}"
      ignore_errors: yes
      tags:
        - always
```

When building in Jenkins, the error I get is as :

fatal: [destination_server_name]: FAILED! => {"msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'dict' object has no attribute'stdout_lines'\n\nThe error appears to have been in '/ansible/playbook/path/main.yml': line , column , but may\nbe elsewhere the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n\n - name: Show output\n here\n\exception type: <class'ansible.errors.AnsibleUndefinedVariable'>\nexception" 'dict' object has no attributes 'stdout_lines'"}

Any suggestions on how to get rid of this error?

Comment: You are not showing us what populates `output`, so, this is not possible to answer you.

Comment: I have added some extra code from main.yml file

Comment: Why are you adding `ignore_errors: yes` everywhere? I guess you are running this playbook with a specific set of tags, from what I see here, it is the only possibility for it to misbehave. If so please give all the informations in your question so we can reproduce. Useful read: [mre].

Comment: This code will not result in the error shown because it contains syntax errors. When you are asking for help with something, manually redacting it will often remove the original bug or introduce other problems than the one you had. It's much better to modify your code to remove sensitive data while trying to reproduce the problem in a minimal way.

Answer (score 1):

Your first task has a condition and different tags than the second task, so it does not always run. When it does not run, `output.stdout_lines` does not exist. There are a number of ways to fix this.

You can make sure the condition and tags match.

You can set a condition on the second task:

```
    - name: Show output
      debug: 
        msg: "{{ output.stdout_lines }}"
      tags:
        - always
      when: output.stdout_lines is defined
```

You can provide a default value:

```
    - name: Show output
      debug: 
        msg: "{{ output.stdout_lines | default('no output') }}"
      tags:
        - always
```

etc.